# SAPUI5 Filtered List inside Panels

Tags: xml, json, mobile, data-binding, sapui5

I am trying to create a page that requires a Panel with Filtered List inside.

What I have before are separate JSON files for the "GROUPS" and "SYSTEMS" but then incorporated them into one.

Here is my new JSON file:

```
{
  "TECHOPSSet" : [
    {
        "GROUP" : "1",
        "SYSTEMS": [
            {
              "SysID" : "sys1",
              "SysDesc" : "System1",
              "Availability" : "1",
              "Performance" : "1",
              "Exception" : "3",
              "Configuration" : "2"
            }
        ]
    },   
    {
        "GROUP" : "2",
        "SYSTEMS": [
            {
              "SysID" : "sys2",
              "SysDesc" : "System2",
              "Availability" : "1",
              "Performance" : "1",
              "Exception" : "3",
              "Configuration" : "2"
            },
                        {
              "SysID" : "sys3",
              "SysDesc" : "System3",
              "Availability" : "2",
              "Performance" : "1",
              "Exception" : "2",
              "Configuration" : "3"
            }
        ]
    },    
    {
        "GROUP" : "3",
        "SYSTEMS": [
            {
              "SysID" : "sys4",
              "SysDesc" : "System4",
              "Availability" : "1",
              "Performance" : "1",
              "Exception" : "1",
              "Configuration" : "1"
            },
            {
              "SysID" : "sys5",
              "SysDesc" : "System5",
              "Availability" : "2",
              "Performance" : "2",
              "Exception" : "3",
              "Configuration" : "1"
            },
            {
              "SysID" : "sys6",
              "SysDesc" : "System6",
              "Availability" : "1",
              "Performance" : "1",
              "Exception" : "2",
              "Configuration" : "3"
            }
        ]
    },    
    {
        "GROUP" : "4",
        "SYSTEMS": [
            {
              "SysID" : "sys7",
              "SysDesc" : "System7",
              "Availability" : "1",
              "Performance" : "1",
              "Exception" : "3",
              "Configuration" : "2"
            }
        ]
    },
        {
        "GROUP" : "5",
        "SYSTEMS": [
            {
              "SysID" : "sys8",
              "SysDesc" : "System8",
              "Availability" : "1",
              "Performance" : "1",
              "Exception" : "3",
              "Configuration" : "2"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is a fragment of the view I made which does not work. I think there must be something with the "items path" but I don't know how to fix it.

```
    <core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m">

<List id="homelistID" items="{ path: '/TECHOPSSet/GROUP' }" >
    <items>
        <CustomListItem type="Inactive">
            <Panel id="homePanelID" expandable="true" expanded="false" headerText="{GROUP}">
                <Toolbar height="2rem">
                    <Text text="Technical" />
                    <ToolbarSpacer />
                    <Text text="Monitoring" />
                    <ToolbarSpacer />
                    <Text text="Business" />
                </Toolbar>
                    <List id="techopsListID" items="{ path: '/TECHOPSSet/SYSTEMS'}">
                        <items>
                            <CustomListItem type="Active">
                                <l:HorizontalLayout>
                                    <Image src="{parts: ['Availability', 'Performance', 'Exception'] , formatter: 'sap.ui.proj.util.Formatter.techMonSummary'}" />
                                    <Text text="{SysDesc}" />
                                    <!--<Image src="{parts: ['enter BizOps parts here'] , formatter: 'sap.ui.proj.util.Formatter.bizMonSummary'}" /> -->
                                </l:HorizontalLayout>
                            </CustomListItem>
                        </items>
                    </List>
            </Panel>
        </CustomListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```

And here is a snippet of my controller...

```
    onInit : function() {
    var homePage = this.getView().byId("homePage");

    var oPanelGroup = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(
            "model/panelgroup.json");
    var oPanelItems = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(
            "model/TECHOPSSet.json");

    var HomePanel = sap.ui.xmlfragment("sap.ui.proj.fragment.HomePanel");

    //      sap.ui.getCore().byId("homelistID").setModel(oPanelGroup);
    sap.ui.getCore().byId("homelistID").setModel(oPanelItems);
    console.log(oPanelGroup);

    sap.ui.getCore().byId("techopsListID").setModel(oPanelItems);
    console.log(oPanelItems);

    homePage.addContent(HomePanel);
    },
```

So basically, how do I implement this in SAPUI5 in such a way that the "GROUPS" are the Panels and the "SYSTEMS" are the Lists inside that panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the path of the first list to "{ path: '/TECHOPSSet' }" and the path of the second one to "{ path: 'SYSTEMS'}. If no further settings shall be applied to the binding you can use the short form, e.g. "{SYSTEMS}".
One more hint. Instead of setting the model to every control you can just make use of the fact that properties will be propagated to child components automatically.

```
 var view = this.getView();
 view.setModel(oPanelItems);
 view.addDependent(HomePanel);
```